# Analysis Services Real Time Trace Logs

Tags: .net, sql-server, service, analysis

I'm looking to get the trace logs for AS (same stuff as for SQL server) in real time. I can't find any .net interfaces to this stuff. So far the only realistic solution I can think of is to run it permanently and have it dump to a new table which I listen to on updates via triggers.

Does anyone know of a better way of doing this?

This is the data I'm after (all of it): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174901%28SQL.90%29.aspx

Ta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the API reference:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.analysisservices.aspx

You can setup to capture events using Trace in the Analysis Management Objects.  Here's some sample code:

http://www.sqlserverdatamining.com/ssdm/Default.aspx?tabid=102&Id=18

Hope this is a start.

Comment: Yep found some code in there, the connection string was a bit of a problem but in the end it turns out it is of the form HOSTNAME\SERVERNAME  in a string passed to the Server.Connect(String) method.

Comment: Good to hear.  SSAS is a bit cryptic on the documentation side.